# Find $\int^0_{-4}f(x)dx$ with the graph of $f(x)$?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I have looked through my textbook and I can't seem to find anything on how to find $\int^0_{-4}f(x)dx$ with the graph of $f(x)$. Could someone please tell me how to find the value of an integral given a picture of it's function?

**The Function:**
[image]

Comment: You seem to have the wrong region shaded. It should be the trapezium below the $x$-axis, to the left of the $y$-axis. Do you know how to compute the area of a trapezium?

Comment: @TheoBendit This image was provided for me, I haven't done anything to it. The red shaded area is part of another question.

Comment: Find the area of the trapezoid?

Comment: Are you simply not aware that the integral of a function is the area under its curve? In this case you have to know that area _under_ the $x$-axis is counted as negative.

Comment: @TonyK That's correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

You don't need any formulas. Simply count.

[image]

I have $-6$

Answer (score 3):

Here's the function in the stated relevant range:

[image]

The integral is the area, which is the area of the rectangle and the two right triangles:  total = $-6$ (because it is beneath the axis).

Answer (score 1):

In much simpler terms, the value of a definite integral is equal to the area bounded by the curve of the function.

For your case, the value of that integral will be the area bounded by $f(x)$ from $-4$ to $0$. You can find that by computing the area of a trapezium. Note that it will be negative since $f(x)$ has a non-positive value on that entire interval.